# Imputing Values Based on FirstYear and LastYear in Long Table Format

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, data-cleaning

I have a long table on firm-level that has the first and last active year and their zip code.

```
pd.DataFrame({'Firm':['A','B','C'],
         'FirstYear':[2020, 2019, 2018],
         'LastYear':[2021, 2022, 2019],
         'Zipcode':['00000','00001','00003']})


Firm    FirstYear   LastYear    Zipcode
A   2020    2021    00000
B   2019    2022    00001
C   2018    2019    00003
```

I want to get the panel data that has the zipcode for every active year. So ideally I might want a wide table that impute the value of Zipcode based on first year and last year, **and every year between the first and last year**.

It should look like this:

```
    2020    2021    2019    2022    2018
A   00000   00000           
B   00001   00001   00001   00001   
C                   00003          00003
```

I have some code to create a long table per row but I have many millions of rows and it takes a long time. What's the best way in terms of performance and memory use to transform the long table I have to impute every year's zipcode value in pandas?

Thanks in advance.

Responding to the answer's update:
Imagine there is a firm whose first and last year didn't overlap with other firms.

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'Firm':['A','B','C'],
         'FirstYear':[2020, 2019, 1997],
         'LastYear':[2021, 2022, 2008],
         'Zipcode':['00000','00001','00003']})
```

The output from the code is like:

```
Firm    2020    2021    2019    2022    1997    2008
A       00000   00000               
B       00001   00001   00001   00001       
C                                      00003    00003
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with `pd.melt()`

```
d = (pd.melt(df,id_vars=['Firm','Zipcode'])
.set_index(['Firm','value'])['Zipcode']
.unstack(level=1))

d = (d.ffill(axis=1)
.where(d.ffill(axis=1).notna() & 
d.bfill(axis=1).notna())
.reindex(df[['FirstYear','LastYear']].stack().unique(),axis=1))
```

or

```
(df.assign(idx = [range(s,e+1) for s,e in zip(df['FirstYear'],df['LastYear'])])
.explode('idx')
.set_index(['Firm','idx'])['Zipcode']
.unstack()
.reset_index())
```

Original Answer:

```
(pd.melt(df,id_vars=['Firm','Zipcode'])
.set_index(['Firm','value'])['Zipcode']
.unstack(level=1)
.reindex(df[['FirstYear','LastYear']].stack().unique(),axis=1))
```

Output:

```
value   2020   2021   2019   2022   2018
Firm                                    
A      00000  00000    NaN    NaN    NaN
B      00001  00001  00001  00001    NaN
C        NaN    NaN  00003    NaN  00003
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, but the output is not exactly what I want. Let's say for firm B, the start year is 2019 and the last year is 2022. I not only want 2019 and 2022, but also every year in between be imputed with the zipcode. See my output that has 2020 and 2021 also filled.

Comment: thanks for the update. However, I do want to point out one possible situation where the first and last year of a firm is not overlapping with others. In that case, the code still only imputed the first and last year, not the period between.

Comment: You can see my edited question description for the scenario that won't be imputing the years between.

I do note that I have a fixed year range for all the firms where their first and last must fall into 1990 to 2021.